# Android Navigation Component and Splash Screen API

Tags: java, android, splash-screen, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Does anyone out there know how to correctly configure an android app to use Navigation Components in conjunction with the new Splash Screen API? I ran into the setContent problem...

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    splashScreenViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SplashScreenViewModel.class);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash_screen, container, false);


    // Handle the splash screen transition.
    SplashScreen splashScreen = SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(getActivity());
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should't make another activity just to show splash screen because you will need to manually hardcode amount of time which this screen will last and it's never good because boot time should be as low as possible. By doing this you slow down boot process and users of your app needs to wait much more time for the content which is the most important thing in your app and not the splash screen. What I recommend is to create a simple logo/view splash which is presented quite nicely in this video.

LINK: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIHArmoq9f8&ab_channel=PhilippLackner